# CRM 4.0 Javascript validation with JSLint

Tags: javascript, coding-style, dynamics-crm, jslint

I've been asked to define our development handover requirements for our partners delivering customisations to our CRM 4.0 platform.  I'm happy to give clear guidance on what we expect with regards to best coding best practice for the plugins.  However, I'm not too sure if stating all custom javascript must pass as a minimum a JSLint with an [Assume console, alert] would be reasonable?

If you are validating your CRM 4.0 javascript customisations against JSLint anything I should be aware of in my discussions with the partners?

Answer (score 0):

These are the options we are using in JSINt[image]